# Cannot use computable knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a view model which is being initialized else where.

```
function PaymentPlanViewModel(root /* root not needed */, item) {
var self = this;
    self.instalmentnbr = item.instalmentnbr;
    self.Abbreviation = item.Abbreviation;
    self.duedate = item.duedate;
    self.capital_payment = ko.observable(item.capital_payment);
    self.interest_payment = ko.observable(item.interest_payment);
    self.overdue_payment = ko.observable(item.overdue_payment);
    self.total_payment = ko.observable(item.total_payment);
    self.capital_paid = ko.observable(item.capital_paid);
    self.interest_paid = ko.observable(item.interest_paid);
    self.overdue_paid = ko.observable(item.overdue_paid);
    self.total_paid = ko.observable(item.total_paid);
    self.INSERT_DT = item.INSERT_DT ;
};

    self.total_remaining = ko.computed(function() {
        var sum = 0;
        sum += parseFloat(self.total_payment) - parseFloat(self.total_paid);
        return sum.toFixed(2);
    });

    self.getPaymentPlan = function (request_orig_id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: BASEURL + 'index.php/moneyexchange/getPaymentPlanForRequest/' + auth,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: ko.toJSON({
            request_orig_id : request_orig_id
        })
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        self.paymentPlan.removeAll();
        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                // self.paymentPlan.push(item);
                self.paymentPlan.push(new PaymentPlanViewModel(self, item));
            });
            self.nextDueDate(self.paymentPlan()[0].duedate);
            })
    .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(status);
    })
    .always(function(data){                 
    });
};
```

This view model above is being initialized in this place,

```
// Initialize the MoneyBorrowedViewModel view-model.
        $.getJSON(self.borrowmoneyUri, function (borrowedmoney) {
            $.each(borrowedmoney, function (index, money) {
                self.moneyborrowed.push(new MoneyBorrowedViewModel(self, money));
            });

            // holds the total moneyinvested count
            self.TotalNumberOfMoneyborrowed(self.moneyborrowed().length);
            // initialize the Money Requests and Offers available table
            self.searchMoneyborrowed();
            /* Read the payment plans for the frst request */
            self.getPaymentPlan(self.moneyborrowed()[0].ORIG_ID);

            self.lastDueDate(self.moneyborrowed()[0].Due);
          });
```

So I was trying to use in the paymentPlanView model, a computed function to get two values and use them on a table like this

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach : paymentPlan" >
                        <tr>
                            <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.duedate" ></span></td>
                            <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.total_payment" ></span></td>
                            <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.interest_payment" ></span></td>
                            <td class="text-center"><span data-bind="text: $data.capital_payment" ></span></td>
                            <td class="text-center"<span data-bind="text: $data.total_remaining" ></span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

All the other values are shown in the table , only the total_remaining value I cannot see. So I am not sure why my computed value is not working. I have created the observables at the top like this.

```
self.paymentPlan = ko.observableArray();
```

So I need to know how can I put that computed value total_remaining, since I cannot see it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remember that Knockout observables are functions.  So to get the value of an observable, you need to "call" the observable.  Your computed needs to be changed to:

```
self.total_remaining = ko.computed(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    sum += parseFloat(self.total_payment()) - parseFloat(self.total_paid());
    return sum.toFixed(2);
});
```

Notice I'm using function call syntax for `total_payment` and `total_paid`.